# Show that $\{1, X, X^{2}+1,X^{3}+X,...,X^{n}+X^{n-2}\}$ is an $\mathbb R$-basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I found a question on a Linear Algebra past paper in which certain notation left me confused (especially what exactly $\mathbb R [X]$ is). I am not necessarily looking for an answer to the actual question, but if somebody could explain how to go about answering the question, that would be very helpful.

Let $2\leq n\in\mathbb N$. Consider the $\mathbb R$-Vectorspace $V=\{p\in\mathbb R[X]:\deg(p)\leq n\}$  and the projection

$f:V\to\mathbb C$, $p\mapsto p(i)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit in $\mathbb C$ with $i^{2}=-1.$

Show that $\{1, X, X^{2}+1,X^{3}+X,...,X^{n}+X^{n-2}\}$ is an $\mathbb R$-basis of $V$.

Comment: Is the bit about the projection $f$ relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: $R[X]$ just means polynomials in the variable $X$ (with real coefficients)

Comment: @ConnorHarris That is for another part of the question, so as you suggest it is not relevant.

Comment: @PeterFranek so if I understand correctly R[X] is all polynomials with real coefficients whose variable is x. Then is it simply a matter of notation to have a capital X instead of a small x, or are there more significant differences? Thank you.

Comment: @user639631 Yes, it can be any symbol, $x$ or $X$, and the $R$ refers to real numbers. Similarly, $Z[u]$ would refer to polynomials in $u$ with integer coefficients (integers = Z).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** 
$$X^2=(X^2+1)-1 \\
X^3=(X^3+X)-X \\
X^4=(X^4+X^2)-X^2 \\...$$

Use the avove to show that your vectors span $V$. Since their number is $n+1=\dim(V)$ ....